# distinguish missing tags from empty tags

Tags: xpath, scrapy

While scraping, I need to detect when a tag is missing, to know the page structure has changed. However, I get `None` whether the tag is missing or empty. How can I achieve that?

Here's a minimal example :

```
from scrapy.http.response.text import TextResponse

normal = '<html><div id="brand">a</div></html>'
empty = '<html><div id="brand"></div></html>'
absent = '<html></html>'

res_normal = TextResponse(url='', encoding='utf-8', body=normal)
res_empty = TextResponse(url='', encoding='utf-8', body=empty)
res_absent = TextResponse(url='', encoding='utf-8', body=absent)

brand_normal = res_normal.xpath('//div[@id="brand"]/text()').extract_first()
brand_empty = res_empty.xpath('//div[@id="brand"]/text()').extract_first()
brand_absent = res_absent.xpath('//div[@id="brand"]/text()').extract_first()

print(brand_normal, brand__empty, brand_absent)
```

Current output :

```
a None None
```

Desired output :

```
a '' None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Querying for `div` element and then for its text() content relative to the previous query you can write a logic to get what you want. If `brand == None` do something, `if(len(brand_txt) >=1)`do something else, etc.

```
from scrapy.http.response.text import TextResponse

normal = '<html><div id="brand">a</div></html>'

res_normal = TextResponse(url='', encoding='utf-8', body=normal)

brand = res.xpath('//div[@id="brand"]')
brand_txt = brand.xpath('.').extract()
if(len(brand_txt) >=1):
    print('div contains text')
```

Comment: From your answer I was able to build my own wrapper function that does what I want. Should I mark mine or yours as accepted?

Comment: :) well, a Solomonic option could be to accept yours and vote mine up. Up to you, the answer was intended to be precisely an starting point for you. Glad it helped anyway.

Comment: I ended accepted yours as I cannot properly upvote you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From Luis Muñoz answer, I made this usefull wrapper that returns the expected values.

```
def text(node, is_attribute=False):
    val = ''
    if node.get():
        if is_attribute:
            parsed_val = node.extract_first()
        else:
            parsed_val = node.xpath('./text()').extract_first()            # parsed_val is None if a node is empty but present, that's what we want to avoid
        if parsed_val:
            val = parsed_val
    else:
        val = None
    return val
```